# How to know in FeedItem Some User's name mentioned or not

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

i have to get those chatter items in which a user name is mentioned.i make a trigger in FeedItem and FeedComment.but and see Body content if it contains @user.Name().but i saw in chatter when i post some chatter like @Ritesh Mehandiratta Hello.feed item will be posted but no link corresponding to to user.when i post it like @[Ritesh Mehandiratta] and doesn't select any user from dropdown still feed will be oposted but no link to user profile on chatter post.When i select a user and then [Ritesh Mehandiratta] appears then i post then a link appear in feed post for user's profile.i want to  apply my action when link of user's profile appears in chatter post.but body of all the elements is same.How to differentiate between them ??